# Defining Winkel Tripel projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm new to QGIS and used to ArcMap.

I'm trying to project to Winkel III and it's not included in 
my version 2.18.2

I came across a thread outlining how to define a North American Conic, which included a link to http://spatialreference.org/ where the user apparently got the proj4 line that they plugged into the custom CRS in QGIS with success.

However, there is no proj4 line on spatialreference.org for Winkel III.

Does anybody have it/willing to share it?

Then again, another thread mentions how Winkel cannot be custom defined in this manner: [image: thread]

Comment: The answer is still the same as in the linked question: it is not possible to use Winkel Tripel in QGIS.